# Create new ID based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| F | 2 |

As you can see for some IDs there are multiple names, I would like to change the ID so that there is a unique ID for each new instance of a name, the resulting ID column would ideally look like this:

Unfortunately I cannot use ngroup() because there are over 35,000 IDs.

| Name | ID | ID_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1_1 |
| B | 2 | 2_1 |
| A | 1 | 1_1 |
| C | 3 | 3_1 |
| B | 2 | 2_1 |
| D | 3 | 3_2 |
| E | 1 | 1_2 |
| F | 2 | 2_2 |

All help is appreciated!

I have used .ngroup() + 1 but as I said there are too many IDs, as well I have used cumcount() + 1 but this makes the number after the '_' go up by one each time resulting in non-unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) per groups in lambda function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and join with `ID` by [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0] + 1
s = df.groupby('ID')['Name'].transform(f).astype(str)
df['ID_new'] = df['ID'].astype(str).str.cat(s, sep='_')
print (df)
  Name  ID ID_new
0    A   1    1_1
1    B   2    2_1
2    A   1    1_1
3    C   3    3_1
4    B   2    2_1
5    D   3    3_2
6    E   1    1_2
7    F   2    2_2
```